# hotspot - Ubuntu 16.04 connects, but browsers don't cooperate

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 16.04 connects to my hotspot, but when I bring up a browser, Firefox or Chrome, I get the error message that says I have no internet connection - retry.

I can go to my in-home WiFi "eldrige" no problem. It's the hotspot that I need.  Please see line 239 on my WiFi info link. It features my hotspot which is called "turtle connector 1".

[WiFi info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24819766/)

Comment: Are you able to ping a DNS server such as `ping 8.8.8.8`?